# Query after POST returns Nil unless following expect(page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

After I submit a POST, I check the DB to see if it is stored.

```
feature 'foo' do
  scenario 'bar', :js => true do
    navigate_to_form
    within '.form-class' do
      fill_form
      click_on 'Save'
    end
    ...
```

If I perform a check right after my submission, it returns Nil on the query.

```
expect(ModelName.last.attribute).to eq("attribute_value")
  => undefined method 'attribute' for nil:NilClass
```

If I perform it after a page(expect) it returns the appropriate object.

```
expect(page).to have_text('text_on_page')
expect(ModelName.last.attribute).to eq("attribute_value")
  =>true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is running in a separate thread. Since `click on 'Save'` doesn't wait for a response, when you immediately check the database, the server hasn't had a chance to do its work. When you wait for text to appear, you know the server update has completed.

Comment: What is the best way to handle this situation in my code? Putting 'expect(page).to have_text('text_on_page')' between these methods seems clunky.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a "best" way, but you need to wait for some kind of response, whether it's a changing URL or some text on the page.